# Effect of $\dfrac{1}{z}$ on the interior of a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Why under the mapping $\dfrac{1}{z}$ the interior of a circle (not containning the origin) maps onto the interior of a circle and the the interior of a circle (containning the origin) maps onto the exterior of a circle?

Please help ! I'm clueless.

Comment: Are you asking why $1/z$ maps circles to circles, or why sometimes the inside and outside are switched?

Comment: The fact that inversion sends circles to circles is a basic fact that is proven in most complex analysis texts.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the mapping $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ maps the interior of the unit circle (with or without the origin) to the exterior of the circle.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: I know that $1/z$ maps circles into circle/st. line. I'm asking "why sometimes the inside and outside are switched?"

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hint: $1/z$ switches $0$ and $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **The interior of a circle (not containing the origin where origin doesn't lie on it boundary also) maps onto the interior of a circle:**

  Let $C:a(x^2+y^2)+bx+cy+d=0$ where $a,b,c,d$ are reals with $a>0$ be a circle such that $0\notin C,\text{int } C.$ Then $\color{red}{d>0.} $We shall show that under $f:z\mapsto\dfrac{1}{z},$ $\text{int } C$ maps onto the interior of a circle.

  $(x,y)\in\text{int }C\implies a(x^2+y^2)+bx+cy+d<0\implies d(u^2+v^2)+bu-cv+a<0$ where $(x,y)\mapsto(u,v)$ $[$Verify then $x=\dfrac{u}{u^2+v^2},y=-\dfrac{v}{u^2+v^2}...(*)]\implies (u,v)\in\text{int }C'$ letting $C':d(x^2+y^2)+bx-cy+a=0$ since $d>0.$

  Thus $f(\text{int }C)\subset\text{int }C'.$ Use $(*)$ to show that $f(\text{int }C)=\text{int }C'.$
- **The interior of a circle (containing the origin) maps onto the exterior of a circle:**

  **Hint:** $\color{red}{d<0.}$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac1z$ will take any point $|z|<1$, and move it to a point where $\frac1{|z|}>1$. Similarly, it will take any point $|z|>1$ and move it to a point where $\frac1{|z|}<1$. So points inside the circle will be moved outside, and those outside the circle will be moved inside. And if $|z|=1$, of course, so too is $\frac1{|z|}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

For any circle $C$ in the plane that misses the origin, $C$ will be mapped (by $z\mapsto\frac1z$) onto a circle $C'$ in the plane. Moreover, note that $C$ separates the plane into two open regions--one bounded (the interior), one unbounded (the exterior). The same holds with $C'$. The non-zero points in the interior of $C$ will be mapped onto either the interior or the exterior of $C'$.

It is easily seen that if $0$ is in the interior of $C$, then the interior of $C$ must be mapped onto the exterior of $C'$, since $\left|\frac1z\right|$ is unbounded near zero.

On the other hand, if $0$ is *not* on the interior of $C$, then there is some $r>0$ such that $|z|>r$ for all $z$ in the interior of $C$. Then $\left|\frac1z\right|<\frac1r$ for all $z$ on the interior of $C$, and so in that case, the interior of $C$ is mapped onto the interior of $C'$.