# Effect of $\dfrac{1}{z}$ on the interior of a circle Q.2

Tags: complex-analysis

Where do the interior and exterior of a circle passing through the origin map to under $z\mapsto\dfrac{1}{z}?$

Linked: [Effect of $\dfrac{1}{z}$ on the interior of a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381782/effect-of-dfrac1z-on-the-interior-of-a-circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the image of the circle. If $w=u+iv$ is image of $z=x+yi$ then $w=1/z$ implies $x=u/(u^2+v^2)$ and $y=v/(u^2+v^2)$. So after substituting in original equation of of the circle $x^2+y^2+Ax+By=0$ one finds that the resulting equation is a line not passing through origin. Now any interior point will get mapped into a half plane.